# iPhone: I resize a contact's image, but when that person is calling, the picture isn't scaled to the screen size

Tags: iphone, resize, contacts, scale

We have an app that resizes iPhone contact pictures and then saves them back in the address book.

When Jim has a normal 1200 x 1600 picture, and he is calling my phone, the picture gets correctly scaled within the iPhone screen so that it shows the whole picture.

When I resize this image to a 320 x 420-something, and save it in the address book, the picture no longer gets scaled, but gets 'blown up' so that I see the center of the picture.

Is this someone has experienced before? Is it a coding error, or a bug in the iPhone?

Thanks!

Comment: Could we see some of the code you use to resize images?

Comment: The code to resize the image is quite basic, something like this: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html We do have an external library which puts the picture back in the contacts list using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the iPhone. A lot of users have experienced that when a picture gets updated through the API, it won't scale correctly.

I ended up just resizing the pictures small enough to be displayed in the top right corner of the screen, instead of expecting them to be resized when someone is calling.