# Sizes For iPhone AddressBook Pictures?

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook, image

I would like to programmatically generate contact pictures - something like what Gravatar does, although not exactly.

Are there size requirements on the generated images such that the contact picture will be full-screen when the user calls?  Are there differences for these size requirements between iPhone 3/GS and iPhone 4?

I presume setting the pictures using the ABAddressBook API will provide no hurdles.

Comment: Well, I've tried setting a 320x480 image and this shows up full-screen on the iPhone 4, but it gets cropped and zoomed for the iPhone 3GS.  This seems really odd to me - I would have expected the iPhone 4 to show it not fullscreen but the iPhone 3 would be fine.

Comment: This StackOverflow question seems highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334926/iphone-i-resize-a-contacts-image-but-when-that-person-is-calling-the-picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases - for iPhone 3 and iPhone 4 (with retina display) I wound up setting the image size to 640 x 960.  When I set the profile picture to 320 x 480 for iPhone 3, the image didn't scale to fit the full screen.

So there you go!